# Detach from screen with C-z

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I start screen like this

```
$ screen
```

I run tests in screen like this

```
$ bundle exec rake. # takes ten minutes to complete
```

Now I want to detach from screen,

```
$ C-a d
```

But I'm more used (muscle memory) to "C-z" for detachment. How can I use C-z instead of C-a d to detach?

Comment: Bad Idea! Read `man stty` to see what Control Z is used for now. If you do manage to find a way to change the traditional behavior, you will have to make this change on every version of every Linux/Unix system you will ever use. ^Z is used by the process running under `screen` - `screen` **May Not** intercept it. `screen` commands are **all** prefaced by ^A. This means that there is only ONE character (^A) that I must type differently (screen/non-screen control), as ^A^A, to send that character (a single ^A) to my process. Retrain your muscle.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so difficult as it seems. You have to create the `~/.screenrc` file with that line inside:

```
bindkey "^Z" detach
```

But, you'll loose the job control feature inside the `screen` unless you bind another key combination for the `suspend` (`Ctrl+K` in this case):

```
$ stty susp ^K
```

Comment: I also want to foreground it by doing my muscle memory command `fg`

Comment: I ask this at https://askubuntu.com/questions/975842/c-z-to-background-screen-and-fg-to-resume

Answer (score 0):

Bind `^Z` to `suspend` instead of `detach`. From [`man screen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/screen.1.html):

```
   C-a z
   C-a C-z     (suspend)     Suspend  screen.   Your  system  must support
                             BSD-style job-control.


   suspend

   Suspend  screen.  The windows are in the `detached' state, while screen
   is suspended. This feature relies on the shell being  able  to  do  job
   control.
```

So, in your `~/.screenrc`:

```
bindkey "^Z" suspend
```

And then you can use `fg` in bash to resume:

```
$ screen

[1]+  Stopped                 screen    
$ fg
screen
[screen is terminating]
```